# "Invalid argument" when sending GET to spaces.members.list

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, google-hangouts

I'm trying to create a Google Hangouts Chat chatbot (in G Suite) using Apps Script. I want to get a list of everyone in the chatroom, but this isn't directly supported in Apps Scripts yet, so I'm using the rest API. The API call [`list`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members/list) seems straightforward:

The command is 
`GET https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=spaces/*}/members`

I've created a service account for authorization and then used

```
var endpoint = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{parent="spaces/pQkgxxxxxxx"}/members'
var options = {
  method: "GET",
  contentType : "application/json" ,
  muteHttpExceptions : true,
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + goa.getToken(),
  }
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, options)`
```

To which I get

> Invalid argument: https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{parent="spaces/pQkgxxxxxxxx"}/members

I've tried encoding the `parent` parameter, but the error persists. Any ideas?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, how about trying ``spaces/pQkgxxxxxxx`` instead of ``{parent="spaces/pQkgxxxxxxx"}`` like ``var endpoint = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/pQkgxxxxxxx/members'``? Because [the document](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members/list) says ``Required. The resource name of the space for which membership list is to be fetched, in the form "spaces/*". Example: spaces/AAAAMpdlehY``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per official documentation on the page you linked, the expected format of the path parameter `parent` is of the form `spaces/*`. The example value given is `spaces/AAAAMpdlehY`

In other words, you are not expected to write the `{parents=` and `}` bits, even though the template URL

> GET `https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=spaces/*}/members`

has them. This template url format is explained in-depth on the [Google API HTTP annotation website](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/api/http.proto).

In your example, the correct URI to GET is `https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/pQkgxxxxxxx/members`

You should also consider that it may take multiple calls to resolve all members of the space `pQkgxxxxxxx`, by checking for a `nextPageToken` in the response (and passing that as the URL parameter `pageToken` in the next call).

You should also consider that the [`MemberShip`](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces.members#Membership) returned by this query may include members with various states of membership.